# Which bond angle will be larger in a compound like CH2X2?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

Just thought of a certain situation.Say for example in a compound like difluoromethane $\ce{CH2F2}$ or $\ce{CH2Cl2}$ obviously the tetrahedral structure will be distorted.

But my question is which bond angle will be larger: the angle between halogen-halogen, halogen-hydrogen or hydrogen-hydrogen? Why?

Comment: Hint: Think in terms of electronegativity of the atoms.